# Angular 9, how can I use a dynamic input field to get info from a list or array?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to get all the strings contained into Assignes array which is a property of Atm object and put them in all the dynamic input, one for each string giving opportunity of updating them or deleting.
How can i do by using FormArray?

```js
atm: Atm; //has an array of string as property 

get Assignes() {
    return this.virtualForm.get('Assignes') as FormArray;
  }

  addAssigne() {
    this.Assignes.push(this.formBuilder.group({ point: '' }));
  }

  deleteAssigne(index) {
    this.Assignes.removeAt(index);
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      model: new FormControl(this.atm.Model   , Validators.required),
      vendor: new FormControl(this.atm.Vendor   , Validators.required),
      Assignes : this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.group({point : ''})]),
      
  }
```

```html
<div formArrayName="Assignes">
        <div *ngFor="let item of Assignes.controls; let pointIndex=index" [formGroupName]="pointIndex">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Assigne</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="point" [readonly]=!isAdmin placeholder="Assigne"/>
        </mat-form-field>
        &nbsp;
        <button color="primary" *ngIf="isAdmin" mat-raised-button (click)="deleteAssigne(pointIndex)">Delete assigne</button>
        </div>
        <button color="primary" *ngIf="isAdmin" mat-raised-button (click)="addAssigne()">Add assigne</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: your Assignes is a getter that returns from virtualForm, yet you add Assignes to it directly, but it does not have a setter... maybe this is your issue? I don't quite understand what you are trying to do

Comment: I'm trying to have dynamic fields, so I can add and delete input field.
The problem is that I need to use those fields to even get values when i need to see the info inserted, for instance if I inserted 3 strings, I need to see the same 3 strings so I can delete one of theme or add a new one

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply even without using formArray. You just need to run the for loop on the array and render the dynamic input fields.

The code should look like the below:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of atm; let pointIndex=index" >
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Assigne</mat-label>
      <input matInput name="assigne{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item" placeholder="Assigne"/>
    </mat-form-field>
    &nbsp;
    <button color="primary" *ngIf="isAdmin" mat-raised-button (click)="deleteAssigne(pointIndex)">Delete assigne</button>
    </div>
    <button color="primary" *ngIf="isAdmin" mat-raised-button (click)="addAssigne()">Add assigne</button>
```

The .ts file should get updated by:

```
atm: Atm; //has an array of string as property 

  addAssigne() {
    this.atm.push('');
  }

  deleteAssigne(index) {
    this.atm.splice(index,1);
  }
```

Comment: so the code in typescript file remains the same? because i got errors if I use this code

Comment: No you do not need to maintain the entities used for building the form. I have updated the solution as per requirement.

Comment: when you write atm, you mean atm.Assignes right? since that's the list of string I need to report into the input fields

Comment: Yes that is the array where you store the data and want to render it in dynamic fields.

Comment: what about the building method for the form? I used Assignes : this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.group({point : ''})]), since you told me not to use form array what can i write there?